# How do I create an automated API test in Microsoft Playwright?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, web-api-testing, playwright

Is it possible to create API automation tests in Microsoft Playwright? If so how do I create the following POST request as an automated test in Playwright using javascript?

Please note below is just an example.

POST

```
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/
```

BODY

```
{
   "name":"test"    
}
```

#### 3rd party edit

The answer given below points to the [playwright api testing documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing) but the problem is, that the documentations is quite brief.

It is unclear to me

1. If i need to create a project first using `npm init playwright@latest`
2. Do i need to download the browsers again or can i cancel this steps because i already downloaded the browsers
3. In which file and folder do i need to put the codes sample provided?

   1. For one code sample the file is `playwright.config.js`
   2. But the first code sample [Writing Tests](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#writing-tests) makes no statement into which file it should be placed
   3. The same is the case for [setup and teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#setup-and-teardown): what are the file names and into which folder must they be placed?
   4. The same is the case for the other chapters: [using-request-context](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#using-request-context), [sending-api-requests-from-ui-tests](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#sending-api-requests-from-ui-tests) and so on
4. How can the sample be run / started / executed?

Comment: Do you need a headless browser for that?

Comment: Yes I think so @hardkoded

Comment: Test for what? Sending a request is not a test. What do you want to assert, check, compare, ...? Why do you need a browser here? Is this a part of some larger script for which you really need a browser?

Comment: I think the question is more on the possibility of testing API endpoints just like in Cypress or Postman. The best thing I found with Cypress is I don't need to have a separate repository for my API tests and UI tests. I was wondering the same for Playwright if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run API tests with Playwright. It can be done in a standalone way without using the browser context at all, and also possible while using the browser context.

Playwright is quite different from Cypress in this case since cypress always considers all tests as browser tests, but with playwright `requests` feature, you can run API tests in standalone mode.

You can see all the required information here.
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing

Comment: For someone new to playwright the api-testing-intro is quite brief; see my update above.